# Changeable CustomListview Background Style?

Tags: java, android, listview

i'm trying to develop an android app. i used Custom listview for array.

i have 4 buttons like that :

[image: i have 4 buttons like that :]

But i want to that : When Yellow button clicked listview's style :

[image: When button 1 clicked Listview's style :]

When Button 2 clicked listview's style : :

[image: When Purple button clicked]

My codes below :

CustomTextview xml:

```
    android:background="@drawable/lstx_1"
    android:id="@+id/ls_txt"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"/>
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class customlist extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {
 private final Activity context;
    private final String[] hikayeler;
    private Typeface tf;
public customlist(Activity context, String[] hikayeler) {
        super(context,R.layout.lsv_txt, hikayeler);
        this.context = context;
        this.hikayeler = hikayeler;
        this.tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "poetsen.ttf");
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lsv_txt, null, true);
        TextView ls_txt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ls_txt);
        ls_txt.setText(hikayeler[position]);
        ls_txt.setTypeface(tf);

        GradientDrawable gdBaslik = new GradientDrawable();
        gdBaslik.setColor(Color.parseColor("#cf96ac"));
        gdBaslik.setCornerRadius(12);
        gdBaslik.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor("#cf96ac"));
        ls_txt.setBackground(gdBaslik);

        return rowView;} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample code is as follows:

```js
private ListView mListView;
 private customlist mcustomAdapter;
 private boolean mStyle = false;

 public void showColor(View v) {
  if (mListView == null) {
   mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_test);
   mcustomAdapter = new customlist(this, new String[] { "aaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc" });
   mListView.setAdapter(mcustomAdapter);
  } else {
   GradientDrawable gdBaslik = new GradientDrawable();
   if (mStyle) {
    gdBaslik.setColor(Color.parseColor("#cf96ac"));
    gdBaslik.setCornerRadius(12);
    gdBaslik.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor("#cf96ac"));
   } else {
    gdBaslik.setColor(Color.parseColor("#849232"));
    gdBaslik.setCornerRadius(12);
    gdBaslik.setStroke(2, Color.parseColor("#849232"));
   }
   mStyle = !mStyle;
   mcustomAdapter.setGradientDrawable(gdBaslik);
  }
 }

 public class customlist extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Activity context;
  private final String[] hikayeler;
  private GradientDrawable gdBaslik;
  private Typeface tf;

  public customlist(Activity context, String[] hikayeler) {
   super(context, R.layout.lsv_txt, hikayeler);
   this.context = context;
   this.hikayeler = hikayeler;
   this.tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "poetsen.ttf");
  }

  public void setGradientDrawable(GradientDrawable drawable) {
   this.gdBaslik = drawable;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
   View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lsv_txt, null, true);
   TextView ls_txt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ls_txt);
   ls_txt.setText(hikayeler[position]);
   ls_txt.setTypeface(tf);

   ls_txt.setBackground(gdBaslik);

   return rowView;
  }
 }
```

Note: "showColor(View v)" is a Button click event.I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But i didnt understand where i put that code ? in custom Adaptar java ? or Mainactivity which inluding listview ? @iOnesmile